# Disable Precision touchpad blocking quick movements during keypress

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, touchpad

When a key is pressed on a Precision touchpad on my Dell XPS 13, it blocks quick touchpad movements - and slower touchpad movements are blocked during the first fraction of a second. This makes playing any game requiring mouse movement like an FPS nearly unplayable. How can I remove this 'feature'?

Comment: See if you can [enable Precision Touchpad](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-customize-precision-touchpad-settings-windows-10).

Comment: @harrymc It’s already enabled.

Comment: Explore mouse/touchpad settings for any such timeout that is too large.

Comment: @harrymc Neither Mouse/Touchpad in Settings nor Mouse Properties have any such setting. There is no entry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchpad or its sub’folders’ that suggests such an option.

Comment: Do you have Synaptics or Elan touchpad?

Comment: @harrymc No. I do not. I have a Precision touchpad, with Microsoft’s drivers.

Comment: I meant the hardware. You may find it in Device Manager under "Mice and other pointing devices".

Comment: @harrymc Listed there are HID-compliant mouse and PS/2 Compatible Mouse. Both list their manufacturer as Microsoft. Same goes for Driver Provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you go to touchpad settings and check if this option is available for you?
You mentioned you have Precision Touchpad so this might help.

1. Settings -> Devices -> Touchpad
2. In Touchpad Sensitivity dropdown, select the option "Most Sensitive"

Then you'll be able to use your touchpad during keypress.